# Change indentation level in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, indentation, pep8

I am using [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) to write Python code in their notebooks. Whenever I hit `enter` after a loop or conditional, the new line is automatically indented, which is good, but it uses only 2 whitespaces by default. This is contrary to the [PEP-8 standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) which recommends 4 whitespaces.

Why is this the case and how can I change this setting within Colab?

Comment: Quick googling got me https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/15

Comment: Note that [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com) ("collaborative calculation in the cloud", another online platform that lets anyone use jupyter notebooks collaboratively) gives you the standard 4 spaces default.

Comment: The answer to the why question is that internally Google has long uses 2 space indentation. It's actually kinda nice once you get used to it since they also use a hanging indent of 4 spaces for things like long parameter lists, so its very easy to visually see where the hanging indent ends and where the block begins.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can change it to 4 whitespaces through settings:

`Tools` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Indentation width in spaces` > Select `4`

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did

`Settings` / `Editor` / `Indentation width in spaces` / `4` / `Save`

[image: Settings, Editor, Indentation width in spaces, 4, Save]